# How to get the Spotlight-like text input effect in menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, spotlight

I want to have an icon in the menubar in my Mac app - and the icon should spawn a menu upon clicking. While having more entries in the menu, I would like to have a top row as a universal text entry field - like it is in Spotlight.

Is it possible to add such a field to `NSMenu`? Or should I do it as a panel-type window?

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using xcode 4 , make a custom view in interface builder and add a textfield or anything you want to it. In IB also drag and drop a "Menu" from the objects library with as many items as you want in it. Then simply ctrl+click the menu item you want to make into the text field (In your case it would be the top one) and drag to the custom view and select "view". Now when you open the menu, instead of showing a menu item in that space, it shows whatever was in your custom view.

EDIT: As for your comment here's what you should do. Make your menu an outlet by opening the assistant editor view and ctrl+click from your menu to the header file that you want to use. now, simply make a method that will run whenever the menu will open, conveniently apple already made this, it's called menuWillOpen.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen: nameOfYourMenu{

[self performSelector:@selector(methodExecutedWhenMenuIsClicked) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

the delay at 0 will make it happen immediately, it must be done in the common modes run loop so that the menu will be updated even while it's open. Now just make the `methodExecutedWhenMenuIsClicked` and set it so the text field responds.

```
- (void)methodExecutedWhenMenuIsClicked{

[[yourTextfiled window] makeFirstResponder:yourTextField];
```

Comment: Thanks. Any clue however how could I make the cursor appear in the text input field when the menu is shown? I'd like to give it the initial focus, and calling [textField selectText:nil] doesn't seem to work... I probably should make it the firstResponder for some window... but for which window? :)

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Hm. Thanks, it seemed to help :) Sometimes I get this text field not editable (and even clicking on it doesn't make the cursor appear there nor me being able to type there) but it's a step forward :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put any view in a menu using `-[NSMenuItem setView:]`. See the long comment in NSMenuItem.h and the section *Views in Menus* in *Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics*.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to struggle quite a bit. I just tried doing the same thing, and reading the *Views in Menus* in *Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics* document referenced by Ahruman, I found this:

> A view in a menu item can receive all mouse events as normal, but keyboard events are not supported. During “non-sticky” menu tracking (that is, manipulating menus with the mouse button held down), a view in a menu item receives mouseDragged: events.

I think we're SOL. Apparently Spotlight pops up a borderless window instead.